Null check operator used on a null value while using firebase signup
I am trying to create a register user screen. But when i try to register I get the null check operator used on a null value.
This is my register screen :
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:todo_firebase_app/pages/MainPage.dart';
import 'package:todo_firebase_app/services/AuthService.dart';
import 'package:todo_firebase_app/utilities/ColorsToUse.dart';

class RegisterScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegisterScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<RegisterScreen> createState() => _RegisterScreenState();
}

class _RegisterScreenState extends State<RegisterScreen> {
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController usernameController = TextEditingController();

  bool obscure = true;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    emailController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();
    usernameController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> signUp(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      print("here");
      final authService = AuthService();
      print("Email: ${emailController.text}"); // Debug print
      print("Password: ${passwordController.text}"); // Debug print
      print("Username: ${usernameController.text}"); // Debug print
      await authService.signUp(emailController.text, passwordController.text,
          usernameController.text);
      reset();
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const MainPage()));
    } catch (err) {
      print(err.runtimeType);

      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
          title: const Text("Error"),
          content: Text("Error: $err"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: const Text("OK"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
      throw Exception(err);
    }
  }

  void reset() {
    emailController.clear();
    passwordController.clear();
    usernameController.clear();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: ColorsToUse().primaryColor, // Background color
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              Text(
                'Register',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: "SpaceGrotesk",
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  fontSize: 36.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  letterSpacing: 2.0,
                  shadows: [
                    Shadow(
                      blurRadius: 5.0,
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                      offset: const Offset(2.0, 2.0),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 30.0),
              TextField(
                controller: emailController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9),
                  hintText: 'Enter your email',
                  labelText: 'Email',
                  prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.email),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              TextField(
                controller: usernameController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9),
                  hintText: 'Enter your username',
                  labelText: 'Username',
                  prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              TextField(
                controller: passwordController,
                obscureText: obscure,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9),
                  hintText: 'Enter your password',
                  prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.lock),
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        obscure = !obscure;
                      });
                    },
                    icon: obscure
                        ? const Icon(
                            Icons.remove_red_eye_outlined,
                            size: 20,
                          )
                        : const Icon(
                            Icons.remove_red_eye,
                            size: 20,
                          ),
                  ),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  await signUp(context);
                },
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor:
                      Colors.yellow, // Manchester United's primary color
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                  shadowColor: Colors.black,
                  elevation: 5,
                ),
                child: const Text(
                  "Register",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                  shadowColor: Colors.black,
                  elevation: 5,
                ),
                child: const Text(
                  "Already have an account? Login here",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

The code doesnot even reach the debug print lines where I have tried printing the email,username and password.
This is my authservice.dart:
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:todo_firebase_app/services/FirestoreService.dart';

class AuthService {
  
  // get firebase instance
  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final firestoreService = Firestoreservice();

  //signIn
  Future<UserCredential> signIn(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential user = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);

      return user;
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (err) {
      print(err);
      throw Exception(err);
    }
  }

  //signUp

  Future<UserCredential> signUp(
      String email, String password, String username) async {
    print("check");
    try {
      UserCredential user = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );
      print(user);
      firestoreService.addUserToDatabase(user.user!.uid, email, username);

      return user;
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (err) {
      print(err);
      throw Exception(err);
    }
  }

  //logout

  Future<void> logout() async {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('Logout failed: $e');
    }
  }
}

I have tried debug printing the data to check if it is null but none of the data are null.

You shared quite a lot of code there. Which specific line gives the Null check operator used on a null value?

One thing I noticed is that in your signUp method you call createUserWithEmailAndPassword and then signInWithEmailAndPassword. Creating a user already signs them in, so there's no need for that second call.

@puf-frank-van-puffelen
onPressed: () async {
await signUp(context);}
the error occurs on this line. When the signup method is called the code stops after executing the first print("here") code and nothing after that gets executed

There is no non-null coercion operator (!) on that line. Can you edit your question (there's a small edit link under it for that precise purple) to show the exact message you get and on what line that happens? --- You'll want to remove the call tosignInWithEmailAndPassword as it's more likely to hurt than help, as I explained above too.

The only postfix exclamation mark in your posted code is in  signup(...) where you have: user.user!.uid. Have you checked that the object user has a non-null field user? To avoid confusion, the variable user should be rather named userCredential.
